# Rails - Owner of data - User, or company (or group)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, permissions, authorization, owner

In the models of my app I want to have the option that the owner of each record is a user or a company...

Normally I have a user_id field (user model) in each model for keeping the owner...

What are the implementation options for this?

How can I design this?

Should I add another field in the models? owner? how can I use the user_id (user_model) or the company_id (company model)?

The data in the app could be:

- Personal data of the specific user
- Company data, which are separated from Personal data. Ofcourse company data also created by a certain user which is a member (with certain role) of the company...

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: This is a very interesting question, but it seems you can get better answers in the https://dba.stackexchange.com/ and/or https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ StackExchange sites.

Comment: You are correct... maybe the softwareengineering is better...
do you know if I can move my question to this one?
Thank you very much for your time :)

Comment: You're welcome ;) I don't know if you can move it without mod intervention, but anyway you can just create them there as new questions.

Answer (score 0):

this can be done with polymorphic associations, you have a model that can belongs to more than 1 model with the same relationship, see this example

```
class Picture < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
end

class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :pictures, as: :imageable
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :pictures, as: :imageable
end
```

for this to work you need to create an `imageable_id` and `imageable_type` on your picture table, fir this example.

you can check more information about this on [rails documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations)

Comment: First I want to thank you for your reply...

Second, in my case, it is not very clear what do you sugest

for the model Product:

class Picture < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :ownable, polymorphic: true
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products, as: :ownable
end

class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products, as: :ownable
end

and for another model, Customer? How it will be? "ownable again? or "productable", "customerable", and so on...

In general I want to capture the owner info of each record in a lot of models...